# Kotlin Errors After Converting from Java

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I do not have very much experience with Kotlin, been doing most of my development in Java.  I have converted my ArtistFragment to Kotlin in order to solve another issue. But after converting it I am getting to errors that I do not know how to resolve.

The first one is *Smart cast to 'RecyclerView!' is impossible, because 'recyclerView' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time* and the second one is *Cannot create an instance of an abstract class*

I searched through Stackoverflow, but since I don't really understand the what the problem is I am not sure if they are relevant to my problems.

Here is my converted ArtistFragment:

```
class ArtistFragment : Fragment() {
    var spanCount = 3 // 2 columns
    var spacing = 20 // 20px
    var includeEdge = true
    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var adapter: ArtistAdapter? = null
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artist, container, false)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.artistFragment)
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(GridLayoutManager(activity, 3))
        LoadData().execute("")
        return view
    }

    abstract inner class LoadData : AsyncTask<String?, Void?, String>() {
        protected fun doInBackground(vararg strings: String): String {
            if (activity != null) {
                adapter = ArtistAdapter(activity, ArtistLoader().artistList(activity))
            }
            return "Executed"
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(s: String) {
            recyclerView!!.adapter = adapter
            if (activity != null) {
                recyclerView!!.addItemDecoration(GridSpacingItemDecoration(spanCount, spacing, includeEdge))
            }
        }

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
        }
    }
}
```

I am seeing *Smart cast to 'RecyclerView!' is impossible, because 'recyclerView' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time* here in this section: `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(GridLayoutManager(activity, 3))`

I am seeing *Cannot create an instance of an abstract class* here in this section `LoadData().execute("")`

I hoping someone can explain these error and how to fix them.

Thanks

Comment: Please post each question separately with smaller code relevant to that particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your recyclerview is a nullable property, You need to modify your code as below -

```
 recyclerView?.setLayoutManager(GridLayoutManager(activity, 3))
```

Remove abstract from class

```
inner class LoadData : AsyncTask<String?, Void?, String>()
```

Comment: What does the ? represent after the recyclerView?

Comment: If I remove the abstract from the inner class LoadData I get the following: 'Class 'LoadData' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member protected/*protected and package*/ abstract fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): String! defined in android.os.AsyncTask'

Comment: It is called safe call, as kotlin is a null safe language, you need to refer nullable variables with this. You can have more details on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html this link

Comment: After removing abstract just add **vararg params: String?** to your doInBackground method

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and assistance.  I will definitely review the link that you provided above in order to understand this better.

Answer (score 1):

*Smart cast to 'RecyclerView!' is impossible, because 'recyclerView' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time* is because `recyclerView` is a `var`. Kotlin has the concept of *mutable* (`var`) and immutable (`val`) variables, where a `val` is a fixed value, but a `var` can be reassigned.

So the issue is that `recyclerView` is a nullable type (`RecyclerView?`) and it could be null - so you need to make sure it's not null before you access it, right? `findViewById` returns a non-null `RecyclerView`, which gets assigned to `recyclerView`, so the compiler knows it can't be null.

But then it gets to the next line - what if the value of `recyclerView` has changed since the previous line? What if something has modified it, like on another thread? It's a `var` so that's possible, and the compiler can't make any guarantees about whether it's null or not anymore. So it can't "smart cast to `RecyclerView!`" (`!` denotes non-null) and let you just treat it as a non-null type in your code. You have to null check it again.

What Priyanka's code (`recyclerView?.setLayoutManager(GridLayoutManager(activity, 3))`) does is null-checks `recyclerView`, and *only makes the call* if it's non-null. Under the hood, it's copying `recyclerView` to a temporary `val` (which isn't going to change) and checks that, and then executes the call on that.

This is a pretty standard thing with Kotlin, and not just for nullable types - any `var` could possibly change at any moment, so it's typical to assign it to a temporary variable so you can do the stuff on that stable instance. Kotlin has a bunch of [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html) which are convenient for doing things on an object, and one of the benefits is that you know the reference you're acting on isn't going to change halfway through

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, this is very helpful.